# Where can I get examples for the license key generation in a C#.NET Windows application?

Tags: c#

I want source code for generating a license key in a C#.NET Windows application.
i got one project but it has some corrupted file... still need a solution
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and I want a million euro. That's not going to happen either.

Comment: license key to do what ? Are you writing an installer ? copy protection ? .. be more specific...

Answer (score 1):

Please check below SO threads

- [incorporating-license-key-approach-for-a-winforms-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447715/incorporating-license-key-approach-for-a-winforms-app)
- [algorithm-for-unique-cd-key-generation-with-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892314/algorithm-for-unique-cd-key-generation-with-validation)
- [how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the following CodeProject article (there are currently four parts, serial key generation is presented in Part 2 or 3, I think):

- [Copy Protection for Windows Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/NbbfArchitecture.aspx)

Comment: hi i have downloaded the test application but it's not working due to
some corrupted file of .dll can you provide me the source on my yahoo mail(manish_parmar_2406@yahoo.co.in)

Comment: Sorry, I can't since I'm not the author of the article :-( ... I just read it but I didn't try it out myself. But I think the source is provided on codeproject.com too (but it might be c++...)